# I'm confused and I don't know if the way I developed the limit is right

Tags: continuity

the exercise asks me to prove that the limit
$
\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{-x^{2n-2}}{(2n+4)(1+x^2)^{n+2}})= \frac{n-1}{n+2}
$

bag out of bounds
$
\frac{1}{(2n+4)}\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{-x^{2n-2}}{(1+x^2)^{n+2}})
$
then I apply L'hopital's rule and derive the expression and i get this

$\frac{1}{(2n+4)}\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{-2n-2*x^{2n-3}*(1+x^2)^{n+2}-[(8n+2)*(1+x^2)^{n+1}*2x*x^{2n-2}]}{((1+x^2)^{n+2})^2})$

If I simplify the previous expression I get

$\frac{1}{(2n+4)}\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{-2x^{-3+2n}(-3x^2+n-1)}{(x^2+1)^{n+3}})$

but that limit is 0 I do not know if I did something wrong o I need to change something

Comment: The limit is indeed $0$... the denominator behave like $x^{2n+4}$

Comment: Your result is totally correct. One more typo in a textbook, I presume. $\to +1$

Comment: One gets $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{-x^{-6}}{(2n+4)(x^{-2}+1)^{n+2}}=0$. You are misunderstanding how to use L'Hopital's rule. $\lim\frac{g}{f}=\lim\frac{g'}{f'}$, not $\lim(\frac gf)'$.

Comment: Claude failed to notice you did not apply L'Hopital's rule correctly. mathlove is right.